# How to use Grafana Version 3 with kubernetes?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am using Kubernetes v1.2.4 @ https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/releases/download/v1.2.4/kubernetes.tar.gz
It comes with Grafana v2.6.0. I tried to change /cluster/addons/cluster-monitoring/influxdb/influxdb-grafana-controller.yaml with monitoringartist/grafana-xxl:latest but this runs Grafana v2.6.0.
It seems kube-up is using some other yaml file to create Grafana service.
Which yaml/sh file should I modify to do upgrade Grafana?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I edited cluster/addons/cluster-monitoring/influxdb/influxdb-grafana-controller.yaml

```
- image: privaterepo.net/grafana304
      name: grafana
      env:
      resources:
        # keep request = limit to keep this container in guaranteed class
        limits:
```

And successfully ran grafana 3.0.4

I was also able to post this file to a running cluster by putting the updated file on the master node at this location (master node periodically creates the RC):

/etc/kubernetes/addons/cluster-monitoring/influxdb/

Comment: Thanks @Drew this was healpful

Comment: @Sion -- be aware: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/31002#issuecomment-241482605

Comment: Thanks Drew. Hit this yesterday and decided to write my own definition and uninstall the addons - works great coupled with Prometheus.

Comment: Nice work. How did you uninstall the addons? Did you destroy and re-create the whole cluster?

Comment: Yeah, only way I found how.

Comment: @DrewOConnor you can also remove the specific addon by running `kubectl delete -f path_to_influxdb_grafana_controller`

Comment: @Teddy Yep, but if a node reboots or the master reboots, it will be re-created and rain terror down on your setup. :)